# Why are the stop words not updating even after adding stop words to the english.txt file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, stop-words

I am using `stop_words` package in Python. The original number of stop words in the english.txt file in the directory path `usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stop_words/stop-words` was `174` and I added a few more and the list became `218`.

I use the following commands to get the stop words

```
from stop_words import get_stop_words

en_stop = get_stop_words('en')
```

`len(en_stop)` still shows `174`. Please can you tell me how to make the changes reflect?

Comment: Not sure, but you shouldn't be modifying system files like that. They will get overwritten during upgrades. Instead, use `get_stop_words` to get the stock list from the original package, and then add your own to it.

Comment: @Thomas I have a lot of stop words to be added and I want them to be canonized as stop words permenantly. The list does not have some very common words like 'though' and 'although'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add stop words to the file. To add stop words you should create a list of words you want to add and then use the `union` function of `set` to create a new list.

```
en_stop = set(get_stop_words('en'))
new_stop = {'newstopword'}
en_stop = en_stop.union(new_stop)
```

Comment: Thanks! It helps.

Answer (score -1):

For including the words in the stop_words module, first find the location where these module is located using command 'python -v'.
It will show location like '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stop_words-2015.2.23.1-py2.7.egg/stop_words/stop-words',in these directory there were many files including english.txt and other.Add some words you want to enter in the english.txt and then import module. The length of get_stop_words is changed.

Comment: Thanks but if you read my question's body, you might figure out that I have already done what you have posted. There is no such directory as `stop_words-2015.2.23.1-py2.7.egg` but only `stop_words` and `stop_words-2015.2.23.1-py2.7.egg-info`.

Comment: What is output of command:-- 'python -v'   then type 'from stop_words import get_stop_words'

Comment: You should be careful when recommending users to modify libraries directly, this is not a good practice at all. OP could however copy the module and make his own, or extend the list afterwards in his python code